# what is the best method for animate 50png?

Tags: ios

i have a 50.png in my animation what is the best method to animate it?
cycle for?
NSTimer with call a void, plus a variable and update my png?
thank's in advance

Comment: You'll have to provide more information than that. When you say animate, do you mean move it around the screen? Or do you mean you want the picture in the png to move?

Comment: sorry, i have a UIImageView and i want to animate it, not move around screen

Comment: Fogmeister is a simple static animation, i have series of png 1 to 50 for animate my UIImageView MyAnimation.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:    
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"4.png"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"5.png"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"6.png"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"7.png"],nil];

Comment: but this is for little animation :)

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006889-CH3-SW8

Comment: See my answer for to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8112698/how-to-do-animations-using-images-efficiently-in-ios/8113027#8113027